# Detect values on same place

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

How can I detect with javascript if at least one value in array is same as value in other array on the same place?
If you can't understand, this example will help you.

This should return true:

```
var array = [
    [
        [3, 5],
        [2, 3]
    ],
    [
        [2, (1)],
        [4, 5]
    ],
    [
        [2, (1)],
        [4, 5]
    ],
];
```

This should return false:

```
var array = [
    [
        [3, 4],
        [2, 3]
    ],
    [
        [2, 1],
        [4, 5]
    ],
];
```

Comment: So you have an array of 2D arrays (a 3D array, but it doesn't help to think about it that way) and you want a function that should return true if any of the 2D arrays have a position that has any duplicates?  Are all of the arrays the same size?

Comment: I tried this, but it worked only for two parts of array:
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var clas = array[i];
  for(var b = 0; b < clas.length; b++){
   for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    var current = clas[b];
    if(a < array.length-1){
     var next = array[a][b];
     for(c in clas){
      console.log(current[c] == next[c], current[c], next[c]);
      if(current[c] == next[c]) return true;
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
 return false;`

Comment: What is this for? Maybe there's a simpler structure you could use

Comment: I want to use it for creating timetables in school. The system will tell me, if the teacher is in more classes at one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function test(array) {
    for(var i=0; i<array.length-1; i++) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<array.length; j++) {
            for(var k=0; k<array[i].length; k++) {
                for(var l=0; l<array[i][k].length; l++) {
                    if(array[i][k][l]==array[j][k][l]) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

test([[[3,5],[2,3]],[[2,1],[4,5]],[[2,1],[4,5]]]); // true

test([[[3,4],[2,3]],[[2,1],[4,5]]]); // false

test([[[3,1,4],[1,3,5]],[[7,3,3],[4,5,5]]]) // true
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't work
var array = [
 [
  [3, 1, 4],
  [1, 3, (5)]
 ],
 [
  [7, 3, 3],
  [4, 5, (5)]
 ],
];

Comment: you don't need to check each child of the 3rd dimension array

Comment: @PitaJ Sorry, I couldn't get it.

Comment: you don't need to do `if(array[i][k][l] == array[j][k][l])` just `if(array[i] == array[j])`

Comment: @SnowBlind - exactly, they are not equal, so it should return false

Comment: @PitaJ But the asker tells that it should return `true`, because `(5)` is in the same place on both `[1,3,(5)]` and `[4,5,(5)]`!!

Comment: @myname Can you please explain why you took the `accept` back?

Comment: Sorry, how can I use it for more than two dimensions?

Comment: @myname Do you have an example array?

Comment: I would like, but I'm new here so I can't.

Comment: @myname Just click on the `up arrow` right next to my answer.

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrayCheck(array){
    var i = 0;
    while(i < array.length){
        j = 1;
        while(i+j < array.length){
            if(array[i] == array[i+j]){
                return true;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is it me or this returns `false` for all three cases above?

Comment: @SnowBlind - for some reason, `[[2,1],[4,5]] != [[2,1],[4,5]]`